# Select all results with all rows set to true

Tags: mysql

I have a `Devices` (unique elements) and a `DeviceTests` tables. For each device from `Devices` there's a max of 6 different `DeviceTests`. These tests can be `true`, `false` or `null`. The type of those tests goes from 1 to 6.

I'd like to extract all devices with no errors for tests: 1, 2, 3 and 6. Ths is my current query:

```
SELECT
    Devices.*
FROM 
    Devices LEFT JOIN DeviceTests ON Devices.Imei = DeviceTests.Imei
GROUP BY 
    Devices.Imei
HAVING 
    BIT_AND(Result IS NOT NULL OR (Result IS NULL AND TestType IN ('4','5')) AND 
    !BIT_OR(Result IS NOT NULL AND !Result);
```

Comment: What is the result of your current query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **DeviceTests.Result** is NULL when the test has no errors. I dont' really get why you would use **HAVING, BIT_AND and BIT_OR** functions. You have a **where clause** that is supposed to present you with options to set conditions upon the dataset.

```
SELECT Devices.* 
FROM Devices 
LEFT JOIN DeviceTests ON Devices.Imei =  DeviceTests.Imei 

WHERE DevicesTests.TestType IN ('1','2', '3', '6') 
AND DeviceTests.Result IS NULL
GROUP BY Devices.Imei 
ORDER BY DeviceTests.Id ASC
```

I am **also assuming** that you have a column *Id* in your *DeviceTests* table and you want to sort ascending by *test ID*, if you don't, then you'll get an error

Comment: Check the location of `GROUP BY`

Comment: I don't think I need an ORDER BY anyway I don't have and ID as such. I do have two primary keys.

Comment: DeviceTests.Result is true when the test has no errors

Comment: If you don't need the ordering just remove the last row of the code. Can you at least confirm if it works?